# laravel's model gets request info from controller

Tags: php, laravel, orm, model

I have a problem with code using Laravel. I define an attribute in a model to get a list. It takes a lot of time. I use this model in a controller. Follow the code:

```
protected $appends=["consume_info"];
public function getConsumeInfoAttribute(){
    //query a lot of information from mysql
}
```

**I'm wondering if there is an attribute in Controller or Model to avoid a query with mysql in model.**

**Is there a setting to tell Laravel when to load this appended attribute or not?**

Comment: Why not simply use Functions for such purposes instead of append? Something like `getConsumeInfo()` and call like `$model->getConsumeInfo()` whenever required?

Comment: You are right,but I'm really curious about it , and I think it's a good idea to get a flag in model to decide when the code works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just remove the `consume_info` from $appends array. You will get the `$model->consumer_info` and that too only when you need this.

Comment: You are right,but I'm really curious about it , and I think it's a good idea to get a flag in model to decide when the code works!